# How to capture a video behind proxy with opencv

Tags: java, opencv, proxy, video-capture

At the company I am behind a proxy and I could not get openCV's VideoCapture to work with videos from a http address. I am working on Windows 7.
The openCV has a java API, but the calls are running not on the JVM that's why the following code is not enough, because if I know well it will be set the proxyHost only for the JVM:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my-proxy.net");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

I did not found any parameter for the API to work with a proxy server.

I could just simply capture a video by the following - but it's not using the proxy:

```
camera = new VideoCapture(url );
```

How could I force my java code, or the installed openCV dlls to use proxy for openCV calls?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a Windows environment variable named http_proxy to the address of your proxy server and then execute your app.  I have not tried this with Java but it works for me behind an enterprise proxy for C++ and Python apps.